# Visual Studio Code Replace multiple files at once

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there was any way to repalce multiple line in multiple files at the same time?

I know under edit->Find in Files

this will show all the desires lines in all the files, however you have to raeplce them one by one, anyone way to just like REPLACE ALL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also Search and Replace across files. Expand the Search widget to display the Replace text box.

When you type text into the Replace text box, you will see a diff display of the pending changes. You can replace across all files from the Replace text box, replace all in one file or replace a single change.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files

Answer (score 24):

- Open the folder containing the files wished to be edited via Visual
  Studio Code. If not exist, create a folder and fill up it with the files.
- At the top-menu bar **Edit** - **Replace in Files** or (On Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, On Mac, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).

Comment: I think the keybinds changed, it's now showing `Ctrl + Shift + H` for me (windows) instead of the upper arrow key (or maybe I mistaken what that symbol means). I'm not sure if it's the same in Mac though.

Comment: @aph The upper arrow key is known as “shift button”.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the misunderstandings!

Answer (score 0):

At the current time this is not supported (read in the link at Common Questions)
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_common-questions

I suggest you to try with Notepad++

Answer (score -3):

Replace in multiple files is supported in latest version of vscode 1.3.