# Visual Studio Code: How to actually search and replace a word in all files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Env**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Visual Studio Code v 1.2.1

**Problem**

I can ***search*** occurrences in all files by **Ctrl + Shift + F**

However, I can't find a way to ***search and replace*** occurrences in all files.

Is this a missing(or hidden) feature in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code Replace multiple files at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897659/visual-studio-code-replace-multiple-files-at-once)

Comment: @IvanZlatev mine is about replacing single word across multiple files. The other one is about replacing multiple lines in multiple files.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Visual Studio Code **v 1.3.0++** has this feature:

Replace functionality can be accessed:

- In the Search View by expanding the Search textbox
- Using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>**, from the Edit | **Replace** in Files menu
- Using Replace in Files command in the Command Palette

[image: Global Search and replace]

Comment: how do you specify where to apply the changes (eg: current opened file)?

Comment: And don't forget to escape any slashes that precede intended capture groups. So if for example you are refactoring `App\...` to `App\Models\...` across files, then your replacement using search string `\bApp\\([A-Za-z]*\b)` will be `App\Models\\$1`

Answer (score 11):

VS Code also supports capturing groups when using regex, captured groups ([using parenthesis](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) can be referenced with `$1` for the first match, `$2` the second etc. `$0` returns the complete match.

## Reversing "abc"

[image: Reversing direction of "abc"]

## Appending "def"

[image: Appending "def"]

Comment: This is what I have been looking for as I do not wanted to replace, but more like append/extend, keeping the original. By referencing the capture groups, I could easily append across multiple files, where some of the words were only matched by pattern and not exact string.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently not possible to replace in all files. The good news is it's part of the [June Iteration Plan](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7253). The feature has already [passed a couple of tests](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8184). So it will be probably released in July 2016.

Comment: Latest version has the requested feature.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1690

Answer (score 1):

As an enhancement, VSCode 1.70 supports search and replace in all *selected* files, solving the 2018 [issue 47166 "Make search tree context menu multiselect-aware"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47166).

See [PR 154847](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154847) (available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/))

> ### Make search tree context menu multiselect-aware
>
> When multiple entries are selected, if someone removes/replaces on one selected item, it happens to everything.
>
> Note: if a whole file (uses `Replace All`) and entry (just uses `Replace`) are both selected at once and either `Replace` or `Replace All` is used, whatever replace action is valid for *all* selected item will run.
>
> For example, if a file and entry are all selected and the `Replace` button is selected on the `entry`, then `Replace All` will be run on the file and `Replace` will be run on the entry.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31675041/178347470-174e2b08-307e-47ac-a0c2-0a726738b5c5.gif]

Example:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/52ffd85f2166bb5580d7be74b527423801c36d4f58a67eefd1b0f77d26451cc4/68747470733a2f2f692e6779617a6f2e636f6d2f64636462376338613066643836323930383339663733636630376436356330322e676966]

Comment: best answer on this thread, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All File:

```
Search =  Ctrl + Shift + F 
Replace =  Ctrl + Shift + H
```

One File:

```
Search =  Ctrl + F 
Replace =  Ctrl + H
```